# JKS file lost, can I create the same file with the same data?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm quite new to Android development and I've had the first big problem. I uploaded my first app and everything went ok, but, somehow, I've overwritten the JKS file thanks to Android Studio and myself and obviously I can't update my app. I've been searching the whole day and no luck, I have no backup (I have now, but too late) and I think my only option is to upload the app again...

My question is as follows: if I remind all the data I used to create de JKS file, is it possible to sign the app with the "same" data?

I've read people with similar problems, but they forgot about their password, which is not my case. Do I have any hope or I'm lost?

Thanks.

Comment: If you lose the combination, you can't open the safe.  If you lose the safe, the combination is useless.  I'm afraid you need both.